# SOQL for ApexTrigger filtered on Name field returns no results

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, winter24

**querying all my trigger name**
[image]

**filtering by specific name. But no result found ?**

[image]

***what is that I am missing ?***

**Note: Same query works perfectly in production**

Comment: Does the second query return 0 records for this specific trigger name or for all? Does it give same result in Salesforce developer console?

Comment: yes its not returning for any name, it was working last week. Suddenly it stops working. @Swetha

Comment: I don't know why, but can confirm that I'm seeing the same behavior from VS Code with the Salesforce extensions, dev console, and even anon apex executed from dev console. *However*, running `sf data query --query "SELECT Name, UsageAfterDelete FROM ApexTrigger WHERE Name = 'Case_DO_Trigger'"` *does* return the expected result. I tried both the REST API and the Tooling API from each environment. Maybe an API version issue?

Comment: Its not coming in production, looks like something salesforce has done in their backend for current release sandbox's

Comment: I was able to replicate this behavior on Winter'24 release org. I'll reach out to the concerned team and let you know as I have further inputs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Swetha please do update this forum , if they are not going to fix this issue in prod it will be major impact to all ISV as we use this query lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Salesforce does not fix this issue, an alternate solution is to create a class with a method like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ApexTrigger checkTriggerExists(String trigerName) {
  for(ApexTrigger trg : [SELECT Name FROM ApexTrigger]) {
    if(trg.Name == trigerName) {
        return trg;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```
YourClass.checkTriggerExists('YourTrigerName');
```

Answer (score 4):

The Salesforce Product team has filed bug `#W-14050962` internally regarding the inconsistent query result on ApexTrigger post-Winter24 release and is working on priority to address this.

Basically, Triggers created before Winter 24 release are not queryable by Name field. There is a known issue created for this scenario - [Customers are unable to filter SOQL queries on the Name field of ApexTrigger with the Winter `24 Patch 4 release](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXYtiAAG/%7E), I will update this thread as I have an ETA on the fix

Comment: One more issue found, @Daniel 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/410524/