# How to over come salesforce known issue in aura component in winter 24 release?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, issue

Following code works perfectly before winter 24 org,

**Component:**

```
<aura: component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="showpassword" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
        <lightning:input variant="label-hidden"
                         type="{!v.showpassword ? 'text':'password'}"
                         value="myPasswordText" />
        <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-input__icon"
                              iconName="{!v.showpassword ? 'utility:hide':'utility:preview'}"
                              alternativeText="{!v.showpassword ? 'Hide':'Show'}"
                              onclick="{!c.togglePassword}" />
    </div>
</aura: component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    // show or hide password
    togglePassword: function (component) {
        const oldValue = component.get('v.showpassword');
        //if true set false/vise-versa
        component.set('v.showpassword', !oldValue);
    },
})
```

Expected: (Working before WI-24)
[image]

Issue: (Click on show/hide button you wont see the difference) (After WI-24)
[image]

Comment: If any salesforce guys see this question kindly raise bug and share us ETA, If you are not going to fix this before prod release let us know, As ISV we need to release new package and manually push changes to customer org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this issue with simple tweak in your code using [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation)

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="showpassword" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showpassword}">
            <lightning:input variant="label-hidden"
                         type="text"
                         value="myPasswordText" />
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <lightning:input variant="label-hidden"
                         type="password"
                         value="myPasswordText" />
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if> 
        <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-input__icon"
                              iconName="{!v.showpassword ? 'utility:hide':'utility:preview'}"
                              alternativeText="{!v.showpassword ? 'Hide':'Show'}"
                              onclick="{!c.togglePassword}" />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

It works perfectly fine in this approach.

[image]

[image]